# Why won't my list crawl when Reindex site is clicked in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, crawl, index

I have set up a list and now I am trying to crawl it. I go into the list's Advanced settings and click Reindex, then when I go to the Catalog settings I get this message under the Search Information header:

> It is not possible to retrieve crawl information as the system is configured in a way that limits access to this information.

When I reindex the entire site collection, the list's catalog settings show the normal crawl information (when the list was last crawled, etc...) but when I try to reindex the list itself, that's when I get the error information. Then I check the Managed and Crawled Properties to see that nothing has been indexed. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

An *IISRESET* corrected this issue for us.

Comment: One cannot reset IIS in SharePoint Online

Comment: You may need to issue a ticket with support then to see if Microsoft can do this for you. I am just stating that with this particular error an IISRESET with our on-premise farm corrected the issue immediately.